# How to customize direction of Ext.menu.Menu

Tags: css, extjs

How can I make Ext.menu.Menu display horizontally on level 1, with the sub menu (level 2) displaying vertically, and then the sub sub menu (level 3) back to horizontal...

So, every odd-level menu displays horizontally, and each even-level menu displays vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Button Group](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/menu/menus.html) example. You could implement every odd level of the menu as one of those with `{ header: false }`.

(So every odd level has a single element in it.)